# Trasmission data sheet for Google OnHub / TP-LINK TGR1900

Tags: wireless-networking, router, antenna

I live in Israel and I ordered the new Google OnHub (which is manufactured by TP-LINK as TGR1900) via Amazon. It has been held up in customs and I need to report the following information regarding the router's wireless transmissions (the requirements were given to me in Hebrew, so I'm not 100% I'm translating the terms correctly):

1. Frequencies (in MHz)
2. Power (in Watt)
3. Antenna Gain (in dB)

I found two "tech spec" pages, one in Google's site and one in TP-LINK's, but I couldn't find the second spec (Watt). I would also like to make sure that the sections I found are correct.

The TP-LINK spec page: http://www.tp-link.us/products/details/cat-9_TGR1900.html
The Google spec page: https://on.google.com/hub/#specs

Can I find a more details data sheet somewhere else? Can you point me to an official technical specification of the OnHub that contains these details?

Answer (score 0):

It is really sad they don't publish the technical specifications.

Doing some searches (google for FCC and the id) reveals their FCCID TE7TGR1900 and their [FCC application](https://apps.fcc.gov/oetcf/eas/reports/ViewExhibitReport.cfm?mode=Exhibits&RequestTimeout=500&calledFromFrame=N&application_id=aumTLCcMApPWf8oV4yRyHg%3D%3D&fcc_id=TE7TGR1900) which has specifications.